# Remove One Drive Site Collection Owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

We are in the middle of migration to One Drive and during that process we had added a generic account as Secondary owner on each one drive account .But when i am trying to remove that account i am getting the error that the URL is not properly formed .My Code is below

```
$objCreds = Get-Credential

Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -credential $objCreds

$SiteUrl = Get-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/XXXX/

Remove-SPOUser -Site $SiteUrl -loginname "migration@test.com"
```

The error i am getting is below .I am sure its not with the URL because i added the user to the site using the URL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i had used my Set-SPOUser command only to remove the Site Collection Admin
Its a small change but i hope it will be helpful for someone .

```
Set-SPOUser -Site "https://teanant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/****/" -LoginName "******" -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $false
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Site URL ends with / ,then Get-SPOSite is tend to error as "URL is not properly formed".Remove the / at the end of the URL and execute the script.This worked for me. So your script should look like:

```
$objCreds = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -credential $objCreds
$SiteUrl = Get-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/XXXX
Remove-SPOUser -Site $SiteUrl -loginname "migration@test.com"
```

FYR: http://www.tcsc.com/get-sposite-site-not-properly-formed/#comment-261431